# Migs Payment GateWay Always Return 400 Bad request

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, payment, postman, mastercard

im trying to integrate my website to Master card Payment gateway.
im trying to submit the form on Post man using the info from the document and the info they gave me from the website 
but its always returns Bad request - 400 i just followed the documentation i have been stuck of three days now if some can help i'd appreciate that

here is an image of what i have tried 
i have tried both post and get request deleted the cookies cleared the cache but with no luck [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the parameters as QueryString to the URL. 
Here is an example:
`https://migs.mastercard.com.au/vpcpay?Title={title}&vpc_AccessCode={accessCode}&vpc_Amount={amount}&vpc_Command={command}&vpc_Locale={locale}&vpc_MerchTxnRef={txnRef}&vpc_Merchant={merchantName}&vpc_OrderInfo={orderInfo}vpc_ReturnURL={returnUrl}&vpc_Version=1&vpc_SecureHash={hash}&vpc_SecureHashType={hashType}`

Redirecting the customer to above constructed URL will lead to the Payment Gateway. Once the payment is completed, you'll receive the payment response on the returnUrl.

Comment: Hello, I got a quick question. Is this `vpc_SecureHash` and `vpc_SecureHashType` parameters compulsory?